# How do I stop Maps and Street View from auto updating?

Tags: google-maps, application-autoupdate

I'm on Froyo.

My phone internal memory is nearly full, so I've stopped updating my apps and uninstalled updates from the preinstalled apps.

However, every few days, my phone keeps auto updating the Maps and Street View apps, filling up the internal memory and I have to uninstall them.

Is there any way I can disable the auto update? As far as I can tell there's no entry for these apps in the Store.

Comment: Do you have root access on your device? Are you using those apps (or don't you need them)? Did they come pre-installed with your device, or did you install them manually (from "uninstalled updates" I guess the former)?

Comment: I don't know if the most recent version of the Play Store runs on Froyo. In any event, in the `Settings` for the Play Store, there's a setting for "Auto-update apps". Make sure that's off. Perhaps toggle the setting to ensure it's set properly.

Comment: @Izzy No root, preinstalled, I'm not using them

Comment: @AlEverett I'm currently on the factory version of the Market; no settings option :/

Comment: "no root" in combination with "Froyo" then rules out most possibilities (with ICS and up, you could simply disable those apps, and with root you could have cut the market/playstore connection). But as Al suggested, even the old market app had the possibility to disable auto-updates AFAIR. Open it, scroll to those apps, open their item, and check through the description; if I remember correctly, with the old market app this setting was done on a per-app basis. For the general settings of the app, try the menu button on your device.

Comment: @Izzy Yes it was, but I'm skeptical that an app entry is there for the factory apps. I'll try, though.